# A simple app to create database and insert into table works on emulator but stopped on device

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a simple app here which runs perfectly on emulator. but shows application has stopped when run on a mobile or tab.

My mainactivity is like this.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    EditText animalName;
    DBController controller = new DBController(this);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        animalName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

        final ListView lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        final TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        final ArrayList<String> your_array_list = new ArrayList<String>();
        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;

        Button b2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        b2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tv.setText(controller.getInfo());   

            }

        });

        Button b1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        b1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String name=animalName.getText().toString();
                controller.createEntry(name);
                this.callHomeActivity(view);

            }

            private void callHomeActivity(View view) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent objIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(objIntent);
            }

        });     
    } 
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

and DBController.java

```
package com.example.dbapp;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DBController  extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
      private static final String LOGCAT = null;

      private static String DB_TABLE = "Animals";

      private static String KEY_ROW = "animalId";

      private static String KEY_NAME = "animalName";



      public DBController(Context applicationcontext) {
        super(applicationcontext, "androidsqlite.db", null, 1);
        Log.d(LOGCAT,"Created");
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        String query;
        //query = "CREATE TABLE" +DB_TABLE+"(" +KEY_ROW+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +KEY_NAME+ " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE" +DB_TABLE+"(" +KEY_ROW+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +KEY_NAME+ " TEXT NOT NULL);");
        Log.d(LOGCAT,"animals Created");
      }
      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, int version_old, int current_version) {
        String query;
        query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS animals";
        database.execSQL(query);
        onCreate(database);
      }

      public String getInfo()
      {
          SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = this.getReadableDatabase();
        String s = null;
        Cursor c=myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM animals",null);
        if(c.moveToFirst())
        {
            s=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("animalName"));
        }
        return s;
      } 

      public void createEntry(String name)
      {
          String s= "Insert success";
          SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
          ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
          cv.put(KEY_NAME, name);
          database.insert("DB_TABLE",null,cv);
          database.close();
      }   
}
```

The app has to take value from the editText and should be inserted into the table. And on clicking display it should show the first row element.

Comment: It shows no errors in the logcat

Comment: If it shows  that it stops, there must be a logcat

Comment: If it shows "has stopped" that it must show you some error in Logcat. If you can't find one, paste the complete logcat to pastebin.com and link it here.

Comment: Without the logcat I can't be sure it's the only error, but you need a space after CREATE TABLE in your SQL statement.

Comment: How can I get the logcat for the application running on another device?

Comment: See here for how to debug on a real device: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html